# spring mysql: Data truncation (data too long for column)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have my class Movie :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="movies")

public class Movie {

    private String genre_ids;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Lob
    @Column(length=1000000)
    private String overview;    
    private String release_date;
    private String poster_path;
    private String popularity;
    private String title;

    public Movie() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getGenre_ids() {
        return genre_ids;
    }

    public void setGenre_ids(String genre_ids) {
        this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public String getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(String popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Movie(String genre_ids, long id, String overview, String release_date, String poster_path, String popularity,
            String title) {
        super();
        this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
        this.id = id;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.title = title;
    }



}
```

and my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/moviesPage",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView showMoviesPage() {
            ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("moviePage");
            try {
                JSONObject json=readJsonFromUrl("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=cbb012e4e7ece74ac4c32a77b00a43eb&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=1");
                JSONArray array=json.getJSONArray("results");
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonMovie=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie=new Movie(jsonMovie.getString("genre_ids"),jsonMovie.getLong("id"),jsonMovie.getString("overview"),jsonMovie.getString("release_date"),jsonMovie.getString("poster_path"),jsonMovie.getString("popularity"),jsonMovie.getString("title"));
                    movieServiceImpl.createMovie(movie);
                    System.out.println(movie);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return model; }
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcher] in context with path [/web-programming] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'overview' at row 1

Comment: Have you checked what the length of the column in the database is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281188/text-field-using-hibernate-annotation

Answer (score 1):

In MySql alter the table if column type is `varchar` then change it to `text`. There are many datatypes in MySql other then text. Like `MEDIUM TEXT`,`LONGTEXT` etc.

[image]

It may be work for that. I have already face this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had `SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement` exception. I have `Date` column and just changed the input syntax from `2003-09-17 00:00:00` to `17.09.2003`. The problem has solved.