# Unknown parameter type: java.util.ArrayList when casting java list to postgresql text[]

Tags: java, amazon-aurora

I have the list values stored in `java.util.List`

```
class DBObject {
  ...
  private List<String> emailIds;
}
```

And in order to insert postgresql database, I am casting it as `CAST(:emailIds AS text[])`, but I am getting the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter type: java.util.ArrayList
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are You using hibernate-types-52 with Your hibernate? Most uncommon types need a special converter to be implemented. Bare Hibernate does not support it. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281188/text-field-using-hibernate-annotation

Comment: @Beri not using Hibernate annotations

Comment: What framework are You using then to communicate with the DB? Plain JDBC?

Comment: I asm using aurora rds and communicating with data api

Answer (score 1):

First consider that the table design has a "one to many relationship"
[image]

If not,

check data type for emailIds field on table it should be a text[]
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html

if data type is also correct refer to below code,

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaPostgreSql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "pword";

        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        emails.add("abc@xyz.com");
        emails.add("abcd@wxyz.com");
        String[] emailsArray = emails.toArray(String[]::new);

        final String sql = "INSERT INTO public.emails(id, emails) VALUES (nextval('emails_sequence'), ?);";

        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Array array = con.createArrayOf("TEXT", emailsArray);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setArray(1, array);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]